# Как вернуть структурные файлы в eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Импортирую проект, хочу запустить, но не тут-то было. Те классы, которые ссылаются на файл R.java, ругаются на то, что его нет "The import ... cannot be resolved"

Смотрю, в папке gen вообще нет R.java. Что делать? Я уже и рефрешил и чистил - ничего не получается...

Comment: 1. правой кнопкой на проекте. Android tools -> Fix Project Properties. 
2. меню Project -> Clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал забавную вещь - просто из архива добавил файл R.java в папку gen и обновил - проблему как рукой сняло...

Никакие чистки, обновления, пересборки проекта не помогали справиться с недугом...

Answer (score 0):

Лично у меня Р файл часто не генерируется, когда у меня какая-то ошибка в xml файлах, будь то лейауты или файлы значений, или андроидманифест - советую проверить все...
так же мне помогало закрытие проекта, и повторное его открытие...

Comment: А что значит "закрытие проекта и его открытие"? Это перезапуск эклипса?

Comment: нет, это значит правой кнопкой на корень проекта -> Close Project, и то же самой -> Open Project

Comment: @metalurgus, чет не помогло(

Comment: а xml проверили все? я имею в виду сам текст xml файлов, а не просмотреть через визуальный редактор...
дело в том, что при выполнении операций "Ctrl+c","Ctrl+v", по крайней мере у меня код очень часто вставляется не туда, куда я хотел...

Comment: Да, посмотрел, вроде все в порядке...

Comment: меня честно сказать, этот дурацкий принцип организации доступа к ресурсам в андроиде тоже бесит, а больше всего этот файл ресурсов...

Comment: Недавно открыл для себя отличный способ борьбы с непонятными багами - просто удалить структурный файл.
Иногда очень неплохо выручает